# Modify the program so that it still prints the string "What's that?", but this time it uses an escape character

Tags: python-3.x

print("What's that?") but please use backslash() to make it look just like this.

Comment: could you be a bit more specific about the requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

`print("\"What's that?\"")` is this what u were looking for? Otherwise please clarify your question

Comment: Yes that's the answer. Thank you.